# WhatsApp chats disappearing randomly

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In WhatsApp, random messages are disappearing from chats chronologically. Messages from earlier dates are missing. Not all of them disappeared. It's happening randomly. Like if I asked something on WhatsApp, the reply of another person is missing. Also, it's happening with messages from both me and the other person. I have been facing this issue for last month when I port my number from IDEA to JIO.

I tried reinstalling WhatsApp with and without backup, but it didn't help.

What's the possible cause and how to prevent it? If it's related, I'm using a Xiaomi device.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything like "this message was deleted"? If yes, it means that the person posting the message has deleted it for all users.

Otherwise, WhatsApp doesn't delete messages unless your phone is accessed by someone who intentionally or unintentionally deleted the messages.